# Tls 1.3 - I don't understand servers ApplicationData

Tags: networking, wireshark, tls1.3

I am analyzing connection between my client and remote server in TLS 1.3. I send all handshake finished messages and my application data with GET request in it. I always get the same response, I cant find what does it mean in RFC document. Can someone explain or show me the place in RFC where this is described ?

[image]